# OpenGL off screen rendering, Is there a way to control the anti-aliasing method?

Tags: opengl

Using `glTexImage2DMultisample(target, samples, ...)` and `glEnable(GL_MULTISAMPLE_ARB);`, its possible to set the number of samples and draw into a multi-sample buffer.

Is there a way to control the method used? (see [this link](http://pcgamingwiki.com/wiki/Glossary:Anti-aliasing_%28AA%29) for a list).

In my case, I'd like to optionally enforce full sampling (FSAA/SSAA), instead of faster, lower quality methods.

---

The reason I'm asking is I would like to have predictable output, across different systems. If this isn't possible, I may have to resort to jittering the view matrix and rendering multiple times into an accumulation buffer *(since this doesn't have to be real-time)*.

Comment: It's no different from on-screen rendering; for most of AA methods, you need to implement it yourself. For supersampling, render into huge buffer (e.g. 2x larger on each dimension) and then downsample it with some filtering.

Comment: @keltar rendering large and downscaling had the disadvantage that line-width, point-size, stipple - are also downscaled. So I'm jittering the window-matrix and accumulating instead *(that has its own disadvantages, mainly that its slower)*.